# Form design using css

Tags: css

Referring to the HOSHI design on this website:

http://tympanus.net/Development/TextInputEffects/index.html

I tried replicating the same in my plnkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/qvU6o8Z9HEhSJtX01Ef2?p=preview

In the original website, after entering text, the label does not come back to it's position but remains on top

```
.input__field--hoshi {
    margin-top: 5em;
    padding: 0.85em 0.15em;
    width: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    color: #595F6E;
}
```

But in my plnkr, I am not able to replicate the same effect. I can't seem to understand why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

A quick inspection of HOSHI's input fields shows that there are JS functions bound to the `focus` and `blur` events which then assign classes based on if the field has text in it or not.

The exact method:

```
function onInputBlur( ev ) {
    if( ev.target.value.trim() === '' ) {
        classie.remove( ev.target.parentNode, 'input--filled' );
    }
}
```